# Postgresql Streaming Replication on Windows failover

Tags: postgresql, replication, high-availability, failover, master-slave-replication

Hello i have setup streaming replication using PostgreSQL 11 on Windows working OK.
How can i manually use the replica ( it is hot_standby=on ) in case Master fails ? 
What are the steps i have to perform to the replica ?

Comment: Do you want to access the standby or do you want to fail over? Please be more specific.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I want to access standby ( Its critical for me to use the standby as master and have available database for read/write.

Comment: Do you want to promote the standby? Your question is still unclear.

Comment: Yes i want to promote the standy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-SERVER-OPERATION) says, there are three ways to promote a standby server:

1. run `pg_ctl promote` on the command line.
2. create a trigger file (if you have configured the standby server accordingly).
3. from v12 on, you can also execute

   ```
   SELECT pg_promote();
   ```